# sqlite3 in python endless loop

Tags: sql, python-3.x, loops, sqlite

here is the code to create database with table:

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('testcountry.db3')
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute('create table if not exists my_table(city varchar, country varchar, status varchar);')
cur.execute('insert into my_table (city, country, status) values ("New York", "USA", null);')
cur.execute('insert into my_table (city, country, status) values ("Los Angeles", "USA", null);')
cur.execute('insert into my_table (city, country, status) values ("Houston", "USA", null);')
cur.execute('insert into my_table (city, country, status) values ("Dallas", "USA", null);')
cur.execute('insert into my_table (city, country, status) values ("Miami", "USA", null);')
cur.execute('insert into my_table (city, country, status) values ("Toronto", "Canada", null);')
cur.execute('insert into my_table (city, country, status) values ("Montreal", "Canada", null);')


con.commit()

con.close()
```

Here is the code I am trying to execute:

```
import sqlite3

list_of_countries = ['USA', 'Canada']

con = sqlite3.connect('testcountry.db3') 
con.row_factory = lambda cursor, row: row[0]
cur = con.cursor()

percentage = [cur.execute('select round(count(status) * 100 / count(country), 5) from my_table where country is ?;', (x,)).fetchone() for x in list_of_countries]
print(percentage)

for i,v in enumerate(list_of_countries):

    while percentage[i] < 100:
        print(percentage)


        a = cur.execute('select city from my_table where country is ? and status is null;', (v,)).fetchone()

        b = cur.execute('update my_table set status = "P" where city is ?;', (a,))
        b
        con.commit()



con.close()
```

The idea is very simple:

1. Take the name from list(list_of_countries)
2. calculate how many countries have non null value in status(get percentage for each country)
3. Update status by order in list_of_countries. One by one.

The problem I am facing is: when I run my script it starts looping and it doesn't stop. However It updates status for first value in list_of_countries: USA, in this case.

Any idea why?

Comment: `percentage[i]` is just a copy of the database value.

Comment: hmm, yes I have been thinking about this as well. Thanks. Do you have any idea how to loop it correctly? for me it is important order from list is correct.